How to call an optional (non-switch) parameter without an argument in Powershell?
What I would like to do is have a script parameter with three possibilities. The parameter name is -delim. So,

the parameter is not called and thus $delim is $null within my script
the parameter is called with an argument like -delim ';' in which case $delim would be a semicolon.
the parameter is called with no argument (just -delim)(like you would call a switch) and $delim is set to a default value, like a comma.

But, 3. is not possible. I have not been able to find any way to do that without getting error "Missing an argument for parameter 'delim'."
Does anyone know if this is possible?

Unfortunately, PowerShell (as of v7.5) does not have support for parameters whose argument is optional. A - suboptimal - workaround is available for a single parameter of this type. See the linked duplicate.
